# Setting Page Scale

Tags: notebooks

When a notebook opens in Mathematica, the lower right corner allows me to set a percentage for the page, 150% being my preference for my old eyes.

Is there a way to set all pages, including help files, to automatically open at the 150% level?

Comment: David, just want to reassure you that there is no shame in asking a duplicate question. We mark them this way to ensure that people get pointed to a canonical answer.